# "Linguistic experts" or "linguistics experts"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which one would be the correct and more common usage? I tried googling for answers but realized that both of them are used. In my opinion, I think that "linguistic experts" is the correct phrase, but I would like to know why.

Comment: Arguably related: [Other academic field distinctions like ‘‘math’’ vs. ‘‘maths’’](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/165995/26083).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ✔ "I'm studying *linguistics*."
> ✘ "I'm studying *linguistic*."
>
> ✔ "Those people are very *linguistic*."
> ✘ "Those people are very *linguistics*."

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**linguistics**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linguistics)
> noun, plural in form but singular in construction
>
> : the study of human speech including the units, nature, structure, and modification of language
>
> [**linguistic**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/linguistic)
> adjective
> variants: or *less commonly* linguistical
>
> : of or relating to language or linguistics

So:

- A *linguistics expert* is an expert in the field of linguistics.
- A *linguistic expert* is an expert who uses or knows language well.
- (And a *linguistic linguistics expert* is an expert in the field of linguistics who uses or knows language well.)

Which phrase is correct depends on how you are using it—as a noun or as an adjective.

Comment: *_These people are very linguistic_ is a very strange sentence. That's not the difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

Confusion is being caused here because *linguistics* looks like a plural (see Scott's link in comment above).

When a plural noun is qualifying another noun it is necessary to take the *-s* off. So an expert in cats is a *cat expert* not a **cats expert*. It is made more confusing by the word *linguistic* existing and making some sense. There would be less confusion with *physics* as *physic* is a rare word with an unrelated meaning, or *mathematics*, as the word **mathematic* does not exist and upsets my spellchecker.

Note that I said *take the -s off*, not *make singular* as it is optional if the plural does not end in an *-s*. You can say *women soldiers* but not **girls soldiers*.

Comment: If you would say _mathematics expert_ or _physics expert_ you can say _linguistics expert_. But _linguistic expert_ is more common, and _expert in linguistics_ more clear.

Comment: Yes, @johnlawler, but the point is that it is *either* a different meaning with *linguistic* an adjective, as Jason Bassford points out, *or* it's an error. However, due to the risk of confusion you cannot assume the intended meaning accords with Jason's logic.

Comment: That's why noun compounds (or any construction that removes linguistic material) are prone to ambiguity.